# How can I ensure a [shared] component is truly a dumb component? (Angular)

Tags: angular, components

I'm working on a project for work where I'm trying to segregate unnecessary api calls, logic and other code which could otherwise duplicate work, or make the application slow and hurt performance.
To be honest, removing api calls from shared components was the first step. However I'm looking for some guidance on the best practices I can follow.

For angular specifically, are shared components allowed to make navigation calls? I'm aware that api calls should be avoided (maybe it might just be the nature of the application I was working on) , again, I would appreciate any thoughts anyone has or links to readings.

Also it's pretty obvious by my question that I'm new to angular and still a beginner in coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dumb Components are usually used for presentational purposes. They can not include heavy logic. To make sure the your component is **really** dumb, try checking the following:

1. Your components is mainly interested in the UI, meaning it's used to present data in an elegant way. It usually gets this data from its *container component* using *input variables* (the ones decorated with `@Input`).
2. If the component needs to perform a particular action that requires heavy logic, it should delegate that to its *container component* using `@Output`.
3. Try not make HTTP calls or subscribe (use the `async` pipe instead) inside your dumb component.

I would advise you have a look at those videos [here](https://youtu.be/9QU_GzcU184?si=KvN5I5A5BPld8gSY) and [here](https://youtu.be/7SDpTOLeqHE?si=DxJjp8CirTXoxlB2) from Joshua Morony, they helped me a lot

### Edit

The description mentioned above works well with simple relationships (a parent component with a direct child component). However, when this chain starts to get longer, you have to deal with the so called *extraneous properties* or *custom event bubbling problem*. To clarify, that happens when you have something like this:

```
GrandParentComponent
--- ParentComponent
------ ChildComponent
---------GrandChildComponent
```

Now, let's assume that your container (aka smart) component (`GrandParentComponent`) needs to pass some data to its direct child (`ParentComponent`). As mentioned before, that is absolutely fine. But what if it needs to pass that data to the (`GrandChildComponent`)? In this case,
you'll have to take the following route in order to pass your data:

```
GrandParentComponent > ParentComponent > ChildComponent > GrandChildComponent
```

You will have to do the opposite if you wanted to propagate an event the other way around (from the `GrandChildComponent` to the `GrandParentComponent`) since Angular Custom Events **do not** bubble.

This, indeed, is a lot of boilerplate to do a simple task. But this is how it works and you have to accept that. Alternatively, You can use a **shared service** or an **immutable store** (i.e. [NgRx Global/Component Store](https://ngrx.io/)) that has all the data required for this feature. Then, every component that needs access to this data will inject that service/store. And if those children want to propagate some events, they can do that with a **Subject** or an **Action**.

Answer (score 1):

Thorny question. One ideal would be to make no http requests in components at all and silo this logic off to services. Some frameworks such as Ionic make use of the notion of a 'page' component, which might be a suitable level of abstraction for a component to make http calls itself - after all, before SPAs, single .html files represented individual 'pages', and these would have accompanying .js files to handle http requests.

You also asked about navigation calls. These belong at the abstraction level of the page, since Angular navigation is designed to replicate the experience of URLs taking the user to new places (pages). It doesn't make much sense to put navigation calls elsewhere. One might be tempted to put them in a modal component, but modal components and their logic can be inlined in the template and .ts file of a larger (page) component. In some complex navigation scenarios where there is a 'dynamic flow', for example, one page navigating to one of two or more alternatives based on user input, it may be tempting to create a navigation service for this logic, and the calls to Angular Router might then end up there, though it's not clear to me that that is necessary.

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed-El-Baldfor your response! I will check out the links you've shared

Comment: Thank you @therearedoors as well. I will propose moving streamlining our usage of services as well